# Changing build configuration to "Release" from "Debug" causes GCD to hang?

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store, grand-central-dispatch

Just a quick question. I'm trying to understand what is happening when you change the build configuration to "Release" from "Debug" in Xcode 5. Currently I have an app that works perfectly under the Debug configuration. When I change it to Release the GCD doesn't seem to execute properly anymore. What changes when you toggle this configuration?

Thanks

Comment: All sorts of stuff.  Some debug code may be enabled (do you have a macro for debug-mode NSLog?) and the way heap is laid out changes, such that a "wild" pointer or unallocated object may go from being "silent" to causing a problem.

Comment: are you using running all your ui manipulation on the main thread?  or are you using core data in background queue, if so you are creating a context with NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType?

Answer (score 1):

A Release build enables the compiler optimizer, which usually causes code to run faster and in a slightly different order.  If you have any threaded code that only is lucky enough to work when run slowly, its luck can run out in Release builds (or on faster devices).

Comment: That's true, I have turned off compiler optimization for Release build and problems with GCD are gone. For those who want to do it, it's under Project->Build Settings->Code Generation->Optimization Level.

Comment: Turning off the optimizer is most often not a fix for the problem.  It only may only temporarily hide a memory or timing bug, such as a race condition, when run on your particular device and configuration.